# Where can I see the current charging speed on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, battery, monitoring, charging

Running `powercfg /batteryreport` in `cmd.exe` doesn't give the info directly (one has to do the math based on the log).  Where can I see the current charging speed on Windows 10?

E.g. on Android I use the AccuBattery app:

[image]

Comment: Windows does not have a native application for this, most OEMs, have a battery application that’s typically installed by default

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, good to know, you're welcome to post your comment as an answer

Comment: Lenovo Vantage is a Lenovo App that includes Battery Information (vendor supplied as @Ramhound notes). Windows 11 has improved battery information as well.

Comment: @John Vantage does not have charging speed info

Answer (score 13):

Type in powershell

```
gwmi -Class batterystatus -Namespace root\wmi
```

This gives you general info where one number is charge rate.

Then, another question is what that number is in amps...

I have three chargers, the 65W that came with the laptop gives me 20 000 - 21 000 (normal charge, not fast charging). Slightly shadier charger gives me numbers 19 000 - 20 000 and PD battery pack numbers 15 000 - 16 000.

Based on the markings on the back of the chargers I estimated that the number is chargerate in mW (not mA as there are multiple charging voltages). This is my guess though.

Same information is in "performance monitor" program that comes with windows (green plus -> add counter -> battery status -> chargerate).

This is how the output may look like:
[image: Battery status information]

Comment: Updated for latest 7.x PS: `Get-CimInstance -Class batterystatus -Namespace root\wmi`

Comment: or shorter version (for PS7+) `gcim batterystatus -Namespace root\wmi`

Comment: @Juha, do you know if there is some similar way to cap the max battery charge or stop/start charging on demand?

Answer (score 0):

I'll summarize the answers the question received in the comments: Windows does not have a native application for this, but most laptop vendors have a battery application with that feature e.g. the Lenovo Vantage App for Lenovo laptops, released by Lenovo.

---

Comments:

> - Windows does not have a native application for this, most OEMs, have a battery application that’s typically installed by default. [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) [9 hours ago](https://superuser.com/questions/1732383/where-can-i-see-the-current-charging-speed-on-windows-10#comment2679888_1732383)
> - Lenovo Vantage is a Lenovo App that includes Battery Information (vendor supplied as @Ramhound notes). Windows 11 has improved battery information as well. [John](https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john) [8 hours ago](https://superuser.com/questions/1732383/where-can-i-see-the-current-charging-speed-on-windows-10#comment2679892_1732383)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an answer as Vantage does not have "charging speed" info